# Need Help With Non-Standard Sized Air Vent Fix

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, floor, vent

We bought a home recently and the upstairs bathroom has this approximately 8 inch by 2 inch wide vent in the floor. The vent cover had been double-sided taped to the floor and has come loose. I have searched every combination of words that I can think of to find a suitable sized vent cover. I have failed thus far.

It appears that the floor is not cut the appropriate size for the vent. It seems there is 3-4 inches of floor covering the vent.

Are there any more permanent solutions than double sided tape or should I just call a company to take care of this travesty? Thanks!

[image: The old cover and measuring tape for reference.]

[image: The floor that covers the vent.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it's a 2x10 register box which someone then improperly installed the floor over, and decided to cove up with a return rather than a drop-in floor register. How very odd. I don't see anything in the pictures that would stop someone from properly cutting out the hole in the floor to 2x10 and then installing a standard floor register in your choice of colors. Unless that material is difficult to cut, or something else like that, getting the hole up to the size of that register box will turn this in to a proper install, or at least close enough.

Mind you, that looks like it could be tile or stone, so cutting it may not be trivial. This does look fixable though, likely without doing any duct work or tearing up that second layer of floor.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is extremely helpful! "How very odd" has been synonymous with ownership of this home so far. The working theory for the previous owner has been "Meh, close enough."